# nofollow links and seo for rankings

Tags: nofollow

I want to know that is it good to have a nofollow link on a page . Means is it worth for seo or it will only prevent other site from getting higher rankings ?

sources :
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en
http://www.relnofollow.org/2013/07/relnofollow-html-meta-tag-for-links.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.


Answer (score 0):

You should use it if its a business page and you are linking out to 3rd party services.

Lots of irrelevant links on the page makes your own page less interesting to Google.

This is more of an SEO subject though rather than a programming issue.

Comment: Thank , but if i link with no follow tag then will it harm me if the link was not present

Comment: If the links are nofollow then they don't exist as far as search engines are concerned. Google may follow them but they wont be counted for or against your own sites rankings.